# Is it possible to send push notification using firebase console to all user uniformly over a given period of time?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am using google firebase tool to send push notification to all users at once. Because of this, all notifications reach the user at the same time and it causes momentarily spike in the number of the API request. Normally my backend system handles around 1K requests per minute but during notification, I am getting 40K request at once.
So Instead of sending a notification to all users at once, I want to distribute uniformly over period of 10 minutes. But I do not find any solutions in the firebase. Please help.

Comment: I think firebase console already provide schedule feature to send push notification at given time

Comment: Split your array 40 times and call api in loop.

Comment: @Kaushik For that, I'd need a list of fcm token which I do not have.

Comment: Yes you need fcm tokens for  that.